# Pattern for delegation in modular JS components

Tags: javascript, events, design-patterns, delegates

I'm looking into breaking a large UI component into smaller pieces, but one thing I'm not entirely sure how to handle and something that I can't seem to find general info about is delegating events from sub-components.

Lets say, for example, you have a todo list and clicking on a todo list will update a sidebar with details about the todo. Right now the code we have is basically 1 file with a template and does all the events for everything. It searches in DOM nodes for data when you click on the delegated handler attached to the wrapper of the list and sidebar. There is potentially thousands of clickable rows.

I'd like something instead that is along the lines of this (*this is just pseudo code*):

```
app.controllers.todos = library.controller.extend({
  init: function () {
    // Store all the todo items in an array
    this.todoItems = [];
    todoItemsReturnedFromServer.forEach(function (data) {
      var todoItem = new app.todo.item(data);
      todoItems.push(todoItem);
    });
    this.todoList = new app.todo.list({data: this.todoItems}); // start with initial data
    this.sidebar = new app.sidebar();
  },
  render: function () {
    $('#wrapper').append(this.todoList.render());
    $('#sidebar').append(this.sidebar.render());
  }
});
```

So, you'd have a todoList component you could add/remove from and you could have events hooked up which could update the DOM, but is decoupled from the data (i.e. you could not have any DOM and it'd work). Now, in our app, if you click on a todoItem, the todoItem needs to delegate it's event to todoList or higher. I don't want to have 1 click event for every todoItem.

My only idea is to have a "delegate" property on the sub component that the parent takes (if supported) and creates events from. It'd have a hash of events and handlers. If the event handler is already attached it simply ignores it.

Are there other examples or patterns for this type of thing?

Comment: you can monitor the list for clicks, and grab an id or other identifier from the listItem (event.target). that way, you don't need to bind any events on items, just inject html made from the template and your data.

Comment: @dandavis The thing is, I want to keep the events part of the the lisItem since semantically theyre listItem events. Delegation is an implementation detail. If I'm setting up all the handlers in itemList there's very little gain from even making it another component. If I'm misunderstanding could you give me an example?

Comment: you can bundle the event with the listItems . the key is using but one method for all items, injecting/fetching any dependencies they might need from a List or the DOM from within. this can be a non-event js property tacked onto each element, or just smart use of HTML markup to ID the item to the item's methods. so, it could be something like itemList.onclick=Items.doItemAction(e.target.itemID, this)... In that case, yes you have AN event on the list, but the action is all in the item method defined elsewhere, likely next to the item maker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a client-side MVC framework? These are created to solve such problems. I would suggest starting with [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

[Here](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/) is a great introductory book. It deals with nested views and models, too:
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#working-with-nested-views
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#managing-models-in-nested-views
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#working-with-nested-models-or-collections

Comment: Backbone doesn't have the concept of sub-views or sub-components. If it does, can you point to where in the code this is handled? As much as Backbone is great (I do love it), I'm working with a homebrewed MVC client that has been used for years and before Backbone existed. It works fine and for something such as just delegating events I dont want to rewrite 10s of 1000s of lines of code for this one particular issue :) I'm just looking for patterns at this point.

Comment: In the book I mentioned there are "backbone design patterns" for handling subviews (nested views; see the links above). This example may also give you ideas: http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/

Comment: The todomvc link you provided doesn't do delegated events it looks like. It's just setting a click event on all `.toggle` elements. I'll read some on the backbone links you posted tho.